# Rstudio: Why M2 for fit statistics work for a single case out of four graded response models?

Tags: r

I write this to solve a doubt. This is the code I used to obtain fit statistics for two graded response models for two groups, College students (925 participants) and Teenagers (1258 participants). They were requested to fill a questionnaire of seven questions, which ought to lead to every case having 6 degrees of freedom.

```
M2(MRG, calcNull = TRUE, CI = 0.90)
M2(MRG_Constrained, calcNull = TRUE, CI = 0.90)
```

With this, I obtain the next output for College Students:

```
   > M2(MRG1, calcNull = TRUE, CI = 0.90)
   Error: M2() statistic cannot be calculated due to too few degrees of freedom
   > M2(MRG_Constrained1, calcNull = TRUE, CI = 0.90)
   Error: M2() statistic cannot be calculated due to too few degrees of freedom
```

However, when it comes to Teenagers, I get this:

```
> M2(MRG2, calcNull = TRUE, CI = 0.90)
Error: M2() statistic cannot be calculated due to too few degrees of freedom
> M2(MRG_Constrained2, calcNull = TRUE, CI = 0.90)
            M2 df           p      RMSEA    RMSEA_5   RMSEA_95     SRMSR       TLI       CFI
stats 20.95702  6 0.001867521 0.04453273 0.02474434 0.06598044 0.1125997 0.9898159 0.9912708
```

My question is this: How is it possible for three cases to be nullified due to having "too few degrees of freedom" and still having a case in which it works? Am I missing some crucial detail?

My gratitude in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, it has been solved, just write "type = "C2""), such as this:

```
M2(MRG2, calcNull = TRUE, CI = 0.90, type = "C2")
```

And there should be new information available.